# Kube js Modal component close doesnt work

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have been trying to use the Kube modal component for an application.
https://imperavi.com/kube/docs/modal/

I have been testing how the modal js works and so far opening works

```
$.modalwindow({ target: '#my-modal' });
```

but it looks like the others api methods dont work

```
$('#my-modal').modal('close');
```

Anyone has has an issue with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That part of kube does not seem to work currently.

My workaround was this:

```
$('#my-modal .close').first().trigger('click');
```

This needs you to use the standard

```
<span class="close"></span>
```

that is shown in the [documentation](https://imperavi.com/kube/docs/modal/).

Comment: Thank you... I did that in another website. We were just hopping to have a the modal close with a kube method.